# How to correctly install wildfly as a windows service?

Tags: windows-services, wildfly-10

I use **Wildfly-10.0.0.Final** and I need two things :

- Configure multiple instances of wildfly in standalone mode
- Create a windows service for each instance.

To configure multiple instance, I have duplicated the standalone folder and rename it to **testDev** folder. I change the offset to 100 in the standalone.xml of **testDev** folder.
In this way when i start wildfly (in command line) on these two differents instances all works fine.

Now I need to use Windows service to start and stop these instances.
I use this command line to install the **standalone** instance :

```
service install /controller localhost:9990 /loglevel Error
```

This works fine. But what controller i must use to install a windows service for the **testDev** instance ?

Is there a way to create a controller for an instance of **Wildfly** ?

Thanks in advance